# Saturation region of common emitter BJT

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

About the saturation region of common emitter Bjt it's written that

In saturation mode both of the "diodes" in the transistor are forward biased. That means V(BE) must be greater than 0, and so must V(BC). In other words, V(B) must be higher than both V(E) and V(C).

I wonder that if V(B) is at a higher potential than V(B) and V(E) then shouldn't the current go from V(B) to V(C) and V(E)? Rather than going from V(C) to V(B) and most of the current to V(E)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the npn transistor in saturation mode, both the emitter-base and the collector-base np-junctions are forward biased, so that electrons are injected into the p-base as minority carriers. The base current is caused by recombination of these minority electrons with the majority holes in the base, which is usually much smaller than the emitter-collector current due to the net transfer of electrons injected from the emitter to the collector. However, one has to keep in mind that in saturation mode, electron injection also occurs from the collector into the base and thus the net transfer of electrons from the emitter to the collector can become very small (zero and even negative). Only in this case the small base current can become comparable to the the emitter and collector currents.